# Button onClick doesn't work in Fragment, throws "null object reference" error even after declaring it

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So I have recycler view with the data from public API. I have activity_main.xml just for the FrameLayout, fragment_main.xml for the recyclerView and user_row.xml for the user row in the recycler view. When I start the app it does not even load up and shuts down with error saying:

***"    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference "***

This is the MainActivity. Its just for the fragment call

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), BlankFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    lateinit var blankFragment: BlankFragment

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        blankFragment = BlankFragment.newInstance()

        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer,blankFragment)
            .addToBackStack(blankFragment.toString())
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .commit()
    }
```

as you can see the error is caused by the Button click. The button is for calling another fragment

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    detailBtn.setOnClickListener {
        detailFragment = DetailFragment.newInstance(idTV.text.toString().toInt())
        fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, detailFragment)
            .addToBackStack(BlankFragment.toString())
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .commit()
    }
```

I have tried doing

```
val btn: Button = detailBtn!!
```

but the error changed to the NullPointerException

Its maybe because the **detailBtn** is in another layout, but I am not sure and I don't know how I would fix it.

Here`s the main_activity.xml layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

Here's the fragment_main.xml layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
/>
```

and here's the user_row layout with the **Button** and with the **idTextView (idTV)**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:onClick="itemClicked"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/idTV"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/usernameTV"
            tools:text="ID"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="#D32F2F"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/usernameTV"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/idTV"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Userame"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/detailBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#E91E63"/>

    <View
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/usernameTV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="#000"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You have never referenced the button; use `View.findViewById()`.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal it's kotlin, findviewbyId is not required

Comment: findviewbyid is not required in Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Please add full code before asking the question. I'd be interested to see where you made `findViewById(R.id.buttonId)` call in your fragment. `NullPointerException` generally occurs in code if forget to make `findViewById` call on the view. It also occurs if you made the findViewById call, but the view you're trying to find is in different layout/view hierarcy. I'd be able to help you if you post the full code.(I do not have commenting privileges as of yet)

Comment: it's kotlin and find view by id is not required

Comment: findviewbyid is not required in Kotlin

Comment: Thanks for adding that! I need to learn Kotlin then. Also, it must be another problem then, referencing a view from another layout/view hierarchy.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `detailBtn` is part of a `RecyclerView` cell. Therefore it's not yet attached to the view hierarchy and might not even be unique in it.

You'd have to define the `OnClickListener` with your `RecyclerView.Adapter` pass the information to the fragment.

```
adapter.setOnClickListener { idTV ->
    detailFragment = DetailFragment.newInstance(idTV.text.toString().toInt())
    fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, detailFragment)
        .addToBackStack(BlankFragment.toString())
        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
        .commit()
}

class Adapter : RecyclerView.Adapter() {
    private lateinit var listener: (TextView) -> Unit
    fun setOnClickListener(listener: (TextView) -> Unit) {
        this.listener = listener
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, type: Int): ViewHolder {
        val viewHolder = ...
        viewHolder.itemView.run {
            detailBtn.setOnClickListener {
                listener(idTV)
            }
        }
        return viewHolder
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean passing the information in the NewInstance when calling it in the MainActivity?

Comment: I added a basic example. You have to handle it within the fragment and the adapter. The activity doesn't play any part in it.